# How to avoid type lock in SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `services` with column `'some_col' bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL`.
When I tried to select rows from `services` with value converting to negative numbers like this:

```sql
SELECT -1 * some_col AS neg_some_col, some_other_columns...
FROM services
WHERE condition
```

I facing with following error:

```
Error Code: 1690. BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(-(1) * `services`.`some_col`)'
```

How I can avoid this restriction and select column with convertion?

I have no options to proccess selected rows further (behind MySQL). Also would be nice to do it with single request (subqueries possible).

Comment: @Sam020 sorry, I didn't noticed that. I renamed column just for query example. Error happen with column named different, actually. I edited question, thanks for remark, but no, it's no relative to `some` keyword, unfortunately

Comment: Ah ok ... I removed my comment :)

Comment: @Sam020 no problemo, thanks anyway

Comment: Have you tried `CAST(column AS SIGNED)`? [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Comment: @Sam020 `SELECT -1 * CAST(somecol AS SIGNED) AS neg_some_col` works fine! Thank you! You can post your suggestion as answer, I will chose it as correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CAST(column AS SIGNED)
```

Does the trick! See [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

You can also edit MySQL config to allow this, by setting:

```
sql_mode='NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION'
```

See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-use-of-NO-UNSIGNED-SUBTRACT-SQL-mode-in-handling-overflow). But this would allow it for the entire server of course.